# Como manter os valores das variaveis numa classe

Tags: c#

Estou a criar uma aplicação em UWP que vai precisar de comunicar com vários módulos (arduino) por RS485.

Neste momento e para testes criei uma pequena aplicação que comunica com qualquer um destes modulos sem problemas.

O meu problema é que a minha aplicação vai ter mais que uma Page e para efetuar estas comunicações pensei em criar uma classe para manter sempre as comunicações a funcionar.

O problema é que desta forma não consigo manter a ligação activa, ou seja, após iniciar a comunicação, este perde o estado da mesma.

As comunicações são iniciadas atraves desta função:

```
private async Task initComm()
    {
        try
        {
            //cParam = PDB.getParameters();
            string selectedPortID = null;
            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            deviceInformation = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
            foreach (var devInfo in deviceInformation)
            {
                if (devInfo.Name == "USB-RS485 Cable")
                {
                    selectedPortID = devInfo.Id;
                }
            }

            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedPortID);


            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600; 
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None; 
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            }
            else
            {
                var status = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(selectedPortID).CurrentStatus;
                // ELDB.attachEvent("E1002", "Starting Comunication Failed: " + status.ToString());
            }
            while (flagComm)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Listen();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // ELDB.attachEvent("E2cC", ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ELDB.attachEvent("E1cC", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Quando tento enviar algo, através deste metodo:

```
private async void writeComm(string str2send)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
            {
                dataWriter.WriteString(str2send);
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                await dataWriter.FlushAsync();
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog = ex.Message;
            // ELDB.attachEvent("E6cC", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Aquilo que acontece é que entra em exceção pois o objecto referenciado já não existe...

[image: SerialPort Status]

Como se pode ver na imagem, "serialPort == null"

Aquilo que gostaria de saber é se é possivel manter esta ideia de ter uma classe com os metodos e apenas os chamar quando quero enviar algo, ou se tenho que alterar o pensamento.

No caso de ser o segundo, alguma ideia para que isto funcione como pretendo?

Comment: Poderia postar um trecho de como você está realizando as chamadas para esta classe?

Comment: @EdneyBatistadaSilva

Dentro do MainPage crio um novo objecto, inicializo as comunicações e de seguida faço as chamadas que preciso para os métodos. Segue um excerto.

 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        cComm cC = new cComm();

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();             
            cC.startSerialComm();
        }   

private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                 
            cC.sendComm(4);  
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer manter os dados fixos? (Ñ ter que passar as informações todas as vezes que for realizar as chamadas)
Se for este seu caso, a solução é bem simples!

Declare seu Serial Port como Static

```
static serialPort Porta = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedPortID);
```

Feito isso, quando setar as informações como, Port, BaudRate, ReadTimeout e etc, estas informações ficaram fixas na configuração da sua serialPort, podendo ser usada em outros metodos e/ou classes(Dependendo da privacidade definida, para casos em que outras classes irão acessar a serial port, recomendo deixa-la como *private* e usar metodos Get/Set para setar suas informações!)

Comment: Obrigado Leo.
Descobri a pouco que o problema não era o que estava a pensar e que partilhei aqui, mas sim a falta de um DeviceCapability. Ou seja, a definição do objecto era sempre Null devido à falta desta definição.